# How to parse a csv file with fscanf?

Tags: c, file, fwrite

I need to parse a csv file with fscanf.
My file is like:

```
nroInscricao,nota,data,cidade,nomeEscola
13893,353.9,26/11/2016,,FRANCISCO RIBEIRO CARRIL
13595,472.2,,Salgueiro,ALFREDO GUEDES
13894,614.4,28/11/2016,Recife,JOAO DE MOURA GUIMARAES
13880,403.2,29/11/2016,Fortaleza,ANTONIO DIAS PASCHOAL PR
13881,373.7,,Sao Jose da Tapera,DONIZETTI TAVARES DE LIM
13882,394.8,01/12/2016,Sao Bernardo do Cam,JUSTINO GOMES DE CASTRO
```

I need to read each field.
The struct is like:

```
typedef struct RegDados{

    int numberIns;
    double grade;
    char data[10]; 
    char city[50];
    char name[50];

} RegDados;
```

It's on the same order that appears on the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje — `fngets` --> `fgets`?  If you're v quick.

Comment: Read each line into a string. You can use `fscanf` or `fgets` for this. For each string you can use `strtok` to tokenise the string based on ,

Comment: @Rishikesh Raje Some of her data contains empty fields.  `strtok` will not work correctly with this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a simpler way to do this.  Unfortunately, both `scanf` and `strtok` don't deal well with empty fields.  I've increased the size of your arrays by 1 each to accommodate null terminators on the strings.

If I did this right, it handles bad input: missing fields, last line lacking a newline, or oversize data.  I used `getline` which allocates buffers to accommodate the data, rather than relying on fixed-size buffers and hoping, but note that this function isn't the most portable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct RegDados{

    int numberIns;
    double grade;
    char data[11]; 
    char city[51];
    char name[51];

} RegDados;

#define MIN(x,y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    RegDados record;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t length = 0;
    while (getline (&line, &length, stdin) != EOF) {
        memset (&record, 0, sizeof (record));
        char *value = line;
        for (int field = 0; field < 5; field++) {
            char *endfield = strchr (value, ',');
            if (!endfield) {
                endfield = strchr (value, '\n');
                if (!endfield) {
                    endfield = strchr (value, '\0');
                }
            }
            int field_length = endfield - value;
            switch (field) {
                case 0: record.numberIns = atoi (value); break;
                case 1: record.grade = atof (value); break;
                case 2: strncpy (record.data, value, MIN (10, field_length)); break;
                case 3: strncpy (record.city, value, MIN (50, field_length)); break;
                case 4: strncpy (record.name, value, MIN (50, field_length)); break;
            }
            if (*endfield == '\n' || *endfield == '\0') break;
            value = endfield + 1;
        }
        printf ("Number: %d\n  Grade: %lf\n  date: %s\n  city: %s\n  who: %s\n",
            record.numberIns,
            record.grade,
            record.data,
            record.city,
            record.name);
    }
    free (line);
    return 0;
}
```

It would be better broken into functions (perhaps a `parse_student_record` that accepts a string and returns a newly-allocated record on success, and probably others too), and I should be using constants for string field lengths and an enumeration for field order instead of hard-coding values all over.  If this was a real project, I'd use `strtol` and `strtof` instead of `atoi` and `atof`, and use the `endptr` provided by those functions to do some validation (expect `endptr == endfield` else invalid contents), but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: I like your answer, but the only concerns would be thin validation and the use of `atoi` and `atof` -- which provide zero error reporting (better to use `strtol` and `strtod` which provide full error reporting. Other nit would be the use of *magic-numbers* rather than defining needed constants. Still worth the UV for the effort and approach.

Comment: Oops - couple of warnings to tidy up: `"warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’"` and `"unused parameter 'argc'"` (and same for `argv`). Just use `int main (void)`; in that case. Your parsing code works very well otherwise `:)`

Answer (score 0):

A flexible and robust way to parse the fields while handling empty fields is to use a simple *start* and *end* pointer and `strcspn` where the bytes for the `reject` parameter are `",\n"`. This way, you can walk-a-pointer down each line, separating fields into the corresponding struct members with a `switch()` statement and pointer-arithmetic.

Taking it step-by-step in an example, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define EMPTY  -1   /* define value for number if empty-fields */
#define NMEMB   5   /* number of members in struct */
#define DATSZ  12   /* 10 not large enough for data string */
#define CNSZ   50   /* chars in city, name */
#define NLINE 128   /* number of struct (csv lines) */
#define MAXC 1024   /* number of chars in read buffer */

typedef struct RegDados {
    int numberIns;
    double grade;
    char data[DATSZ]; 
    char city[CNSZ];
    char name[CNSZ];
} RegDados;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* read buffer */
    size_t ndx = 0;     /* struct index */
    /* initialize array of struct */
    RegDados reg[NLINE] = {{ .numberIns = EMPTY, .grade = EMPTY }};
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    fgets (buf, MAXC, fp);  /* read/discard header line */

    /* read each line up to a max of NLINE lines */
    while (ndx < NLINE && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        size_t n = 0;   /* current field number */
        char *p = buf,  /* beginning pointer in field */
            *ep = p + strcspn (p, ",\n");   /* end pointer in field */

        while (*p && *p != '\n') {  /* for each field */
            switch (n) {    /* switch on field number */
                case 0:
                    if (ep > p && isdigit (*p)) {   /* non-empty w/digit */
                        char *endptr;   /* endptr for strtol */
                        long tmp = strtol (p, &endptr, 0);  /* convert */
                        if (p == endptr)    /* validate */
                            fputs ("error: no digits, numberIns.\n", stderr);
                        else if (errno)
                            fputs ("error: over/underflow.\n", stderr);
                        else if (tmp < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < tmp)
                            fputs ("error: exceeds range of int.\n", stderr);
                        else
                            reg[ndx].numberIns = tmp;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (ep > p && isdigit (*p)) {   /* non-empty w/digit */
                        char *endptr;   /* endptr for strtod */
                        double tmp = strtod (p, &endptr);   /* convert */
                        if (p == endptr)    /* validate */
                            fputs ("error: no digits, numberIns.\n", stderr);
                        else if (errno)
                            fputs ("error: over/underflow.\n", stderr);
                        else
                            reg[ndx].grade = tmp;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (ep > p && ep - p < DATSZ) { /* chars, will it fit? */
                        memcpy (reg[ndx].data, p, ep - p);  /* copy chars */
                        reg[ndx].data[ep - p] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (ep > p && ep - p < CNSZ) {  /* chars, will it fit? */
                        memcpy (reg[ndx].city, p, ep - p);  /* copy chars */
                        reg[ndx].city[ep - p] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (ep > p && ep - p < CNSZ) {  /* chars, will it fit? */
                        memcpy (reg[ndx].name, p, ep - p);  /* copy chars */
                        reg[ndx].name[ep - p] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */
                    }
                    break;
                default:    /* set default to indicate error */
                    fputs ("error: you shouldn't get here.\n", stderr);
                    break;
            }
            p = ++ep;       /* set p to beginning of next field */
            ep = p + strcspn (p, ",\n");    /* find end of field */
            n++;    /* increment field count */
        }
        ndx++;      /* increment index */
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)    /* output data */
        printf ("%6d %6.1f  %-12s %-20s %s\n", reg[i].numberIns,
                reg[i].grade, reg[i].data, reg[i].city, reg[i].name);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/csvwempty.csv
nroInscricao,nota,data,cidade,nomeEscola
13893,353.9,26/11/2016,,FRANCISCO RIBEIRO CARRIL
13595,472.2,,Salgueiro,ALFREDO GUEDES
13894,614.4,28/11/2016,Recife,JOAO DE MOURA GUIMARAES
13880,403.2,29/11/2016,Fortaleza,ANTONIO DIAS PASCHOAL PR
13881,373.7,,Sao Jose da Tapera,DONIZETTI TAVARES DE LIM
13882,394.8,01/12/2016,Sao Bernardo do Cam,JUSTINO GOMES DE CASTRO
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parsecsv dat/csvwempty.csv
 13893  353.9  26/11/2016                        FRANCISCO RIBEIRO CARRIL
 13595  472.2               Salgueiro            ALFREDO GUEDES
 13894  614.4  28/11/2016   Recife               JOAO DE MOURA GUIMARAES
 13880  403.2  29/11/2016   Fortaleza            ANTONIO DIAS PASCHOAL PR
 13881  373.7               Sao Jose da Tapera   DONIZETTI TAVARES DE LIM
 13882  394.8  01/12/2016   Sao Bernardo do Cam  JUSTINO GOMES DE CASTRO
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

`strsep` will handle empty fields:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    char line[1024];
    char *tok;
    char *copy;
    while(gets(line)){
                copy=&line;//strdup(line);
                int pos=0;
                while((tok=strsep(&copy,","))!=NULL){
                        printf("Token is: %s. Position is: %d\n",tok,pos);
                        pos++;
                        //Do stuff here based on position and null/string value
                }
                free(copy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```